# Siri Shortcuts: How to retrieve list of donated INInteraction(s) by my app

Tags: swift, sirishortcuts

Is there a way to retrieve a list of interactions (`INInteraction`) that my app has donated?

I'd like to avoid duplicating code and having this list helps.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @user4992124 No, I did not.

Comment: Any update 4 years later?

Comment: I think the answer is that apps are not allowed to discover existing Siri Shortcuts (not even the ones that the user has created using your own app)